# How to add an icon to my autocomplete jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on this website for fun to search items with description and some other info, but I would like to add an icon to the autocomplete to give it more meaning, I tried multiple things but I couldn't figure it out, I'd appreciate any help, thanks!

This is my script, I am using jquery.autocomplete

```
$(function(){
  var items = [
    { value: 'Chittering Mandible', data: 'Best in slot..',  },


  ];


  $('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
    lookup: currencies,
    onSelect: function (suggestion) {
      var thehtml = '<strong>Item Name:</strong> ' + suggestion.value + ' <br> <strong>data:</strong> ' + suggestion.data;
      $('#outputcontent').html(thehtml);
    }
  });


});
```

Comment: When you say you've tried multiple things, what have you tried? Have you looked at (for example) the bootstrap icon set?

Comment: I am still new to scripting and jQuery, I only tried what I understood and I probably did it wrong so I really dont know what to exactly say.

Comment: Try taking a peek at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774332/display-an-icon-in-jquery-ui-autocomplete-results

Comment: I was just looking at it, i'll see what I can use from it and try it out, thanks!